# I am new to Ubuntu and need some assistance. I have an issue with an rfkill issue

Tags: dual-boot

I have an old laptop that I have tried a few distros on, and I have decided that I would like to install Mint on my Ssung laptop. I installed as dual boot with windows 10 and seemed to work fine. Now every time I try to boot to Mint, I get a message that makes no sense to me. I have tried numerous help sites and cannot find what to do, so any help would be appreciated. I am ready to wipe windows and have only mint on my laptop. "Failed to start load/save RF Kill switch status" This just continues to loop, and I cannot get past this. I used testdisk and received the following:-

```
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P EFI System                  2048     534527     532480 [EFI System Partition] [SYSTEM]
 D MS Data                   567296    2615295    2048000
 D MS Data                  2308131   32446491   30138361 [SAMSUNG_REC2]
 D MS Data                 32446491   62584851   30138361
 P Mac HFS                 95421331  804258708  708837378 [$no_construct_double_linked]
 P Linux filesys. data   1195761664 1953523711  757762048

Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
                P=Primary  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
FAT32, blocksize=4096, 272 MB / 260 MiB
```

Some system info is below

lonny@lonny:~$ sudo dmidecode -t system

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
        Product Name: 940X5N
        Version: P05AGQ
        Serial Number: 0TQZ91AN400019
        UUID: ec202640-746d-11ea-8519-bdfcf5981a00
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: SCAI-A5A5-A5A5-A5A5-PAGQ
        Family: Notebook 9 Series

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
        Option 1: ASCI:FFFFFFFF

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
        Status: No errors detected
```

lonny@lonny:~$ sudo dmidecode -t bios

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
        Version: P05AGQ.033.181123.PS
        Release Date: 11/23/2018
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 16 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                BIOS ROM is socketed
                EDD is supported
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 5.12
```

lonny@lonny:~$ sudo dmidecode -t processor

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: U3E1
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Core i7
        Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
        ID: EA 06 08 00 FF FB EB BF
        Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 142, Stepping 10
        Flags:
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
                VME (Virtual mode extension)
                DE (Debugging extension)
                PSE (Page size extension)
                TSC (Time stamp counter)
                MSR (Model specific registers)
                PAE (Physical address extension)
                MCE (Machine check exception)
                CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
                APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
                SEP (Fast system call)
                MTRR (Memory type range registers)
                PGE (Page global enable)
                MCA (Machine check architecture)
                CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
                PAT (Page attribute table)
                PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
                CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
                DS (Debug store)
                ACPI (ACPI supported)
                MMX (MMX technology supported)
                FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
                SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
                SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
                SS (Self-snoop)
                HTT (Multi-threading)
                TM (Thermal monitor supported)
                PBE (Pending break enabled)
        Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
        Voltage: 0.7 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 8300 MHz
        Current Speed: 1700 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Socket BGA1356
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x001A
        L2 Cache Handle: 0x001B
        L3 Cache Handle: 0x001C
        Serial Number: None
        Asset Tag: No Asset Tag
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Core Count: 4
        Core Enabled: 4
        Thread Count: 8
        Characteristics:
                64-bit capable
                Multi-Core
                Hardware Thread
                Execute Protection
                Enhanced Virtualization
                Power/Performance Control
```

Comment: which of the hundreds of similar issues you can find by searching for the phrase *Failed to start load/save RF Kill switch status* have you tried?

Comment: I have tried, spent hours reading, and I cannot find an issue that matches what I have.

Comment: you say "it seemed to work fine" - so at one point it worked. Did you do an update to mint just before it stopped being fine? Something changed (I see there's some talk of this issue in kernel 5.11 for example)

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance everyone. I am still stuck with this issue. Everything was fine until the updates were installed and I restarted. I am just really frustrated with this, because it runs just fine on an older laptop. I believe I will just need to go with another distro? int was really more for my wife, as she thought it was a lot like windows. She would just be able to pretty much use it as she does now. I do all the maintenance and updates anyway.

Comment: can you boot to an older kernel - assuming the update that killed it updated the kernel

Comment: I have given up on Mint, and moved to Kubuntu. I believe that it is something to do with the boot logs. I have done a lot of looking at this, and it looks as though Microsoft has had them make changes to make it hard to use anything but windows.